# Get an audio stream from URI and play it on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I would like to get an audio stream from URL and play it on iPhone. Unfortunately, there is only C# example of how to play that stream, but I need a realization on Objective C in iPhone frameworks. I have tried my self to use different audio frameworks but it was all unsuccessful. This is what in C#:

```
response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(stream))
                {
                    player.PlaySync();
                }
            }
```

What should I do in objective C to get a stream audio from that url? In that URL I don't have an mp3 file or something, I just get a stream. Probably I must somehow download that stream to an iPhone audio file and then play it to get rid of lags.

I tried this:

```
 AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
 [player play];
```

And this:

```
AVAudioPlayer *theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url error:nil];

    [theAudio setVolume :0.50]; //setting the volume

    [theAudio play];
```

Neither worked. 
I have tested my url, it works well in browser.

This is the code that worked:

```
NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;

    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:_objectData error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
    audioPlayer.volume = 1.0f;
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

    if (audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    else
        [audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
NSString* resourcePath = url; //your url
NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:resourcePath]];
NSError *error;

app.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:_objectData error:&error];
app.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
app.audioPlayer.volume = 1.0f;
[app.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

if (app.audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
else
    [app.audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: But it first download all data into NSData object.It is not streaming.

Comment: It does not do audio streaming, please share some link to audio stream

Comment: it doesn't play online. It still download. And if your mp3 is a huge file. RIP this code will give you a life time waiting.

Comment: @MonikaPatel Yes I did

Comment: @AsifHabib if u dn't mind then can u  pls share your  demo with me?

Comment: Used open source library! there are many available like this -> https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

Answer (score 14):

Hey I faced this problem of audio streaming for a radio application. I had searched for the answers and they did not work. AVAudioPlayer is not the class to be used here. Downloading the contents of URL using NSData object is not the solution either as it downloads the contents then the code further executes. It is similar to downloading a mp3 and then playing it locally on a player.

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:resourcePath]]; //Downloads the contents of the url and in case of radio the url's content is unlimited. The program gets frozen on executing this.
```

Instead use AVPlayer class.

This code worked in my radio application

```
AVPlayer *objAVPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
[objAVPlayer play];
```

This code does not download the contents at the url but it plays the stream as it is received.

Comment: Are you sure? Where did you read about this? I thin AVPlayer download full data package, and after that play audio

Comment: @Sergey Stadnik It depends on the url being a stream URL. If you use NSData for a stream URL it keeps on filling the data buffer until the stream finishes. This is not desirable for a radio style play. If you want a radio style play for stream URL, AVPlayer gives us the desired effect.

Comment: I have tried to play music from Bropbox with using AVPlayer with URL, and every time I wait 4 - 5 seconds from start... IDK why. Audio track size - 4 MB. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sergey Stadnik, As far as I know drop box downloads are not streams, so AVPlayer will download it and then play in your case.

Comment: Maybe, but I have seen a lot of application, which play audio from DB immediately after click. How they can do this?

Comment: @SergeyStadnik I will have to look at this. Will reply back If I come across something helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Look into the [AVPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, part of the AVFoundation framework... this is the objective-c (iOS) class you use for streaming audio.

Answer (score 0):

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player;
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init] ;
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
player.view.hidden = YES;
[self.view addSubview: [wikiMusicPlayer view]];

NSString *address = Your URL;
address = [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:address];
[wikiMusicPlayer setContentURL:url];
[wikiMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
[wikiMusicPlayer setShouldAutoplay: NO];
[wikiMusicPlayer play];
```

Comment: What is wikiMusicPlayer ??