# How to download audio and play it at the same time on iphone?

Tags: iphone, audio

I mean i want to play an audio as stream, as while as save it to local file on iPhone.

Anybody knows how?

Special thanks!

Comment: [check this open source project](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StitchedStreamPlayer/Listings/Classes_MyPlayerLayerView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010092-Classes_MyPlayerLayerView_m-DontLinkElementID_6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer can do this thing:

https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps for solution:

1. Firstly download audio
2. Play downloaded audio
3. Save downloaded audio in local directory

Refer [Get an audio stream from URI and play it on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6856828/1106035) link.

Comment: But user may need to wait for downloading

Comment: but https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer in M.Othman's commit can. Thanks for help :D

Comment: its streaming not downloading. here we download then play and save downloaded