# How to play AVAudioplayer in iOS.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer

I am working on AVAudioplyaer according to my project requirement.

My problem is, that if I click the play button the audio-player should not play.

I already bind the web-services. I am using JSON parser.I got JSON Response and JSON data also.

I am newly working on Audioplayer.

Please guide me anybody.

Thanks in advance.

```
-(void)loadData
{

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"My url"]];

[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

NSError *jsonError = nil;

id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];

if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

//NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)jsonObject;

}

else if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){

NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;

NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]init];

array=[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"audio-urls"];

dataDictionary=[array objectAtIndex:0];

//NSLog(@"%@",dataDictionary);

}

[urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Audio1"]];

[urlsArray addObject:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Audio2"]];


NSLog(@"%@",urlsArray);

}

-(void)playOrPauseButtonPressed:(id)sender

{

if(playing==NO)

{

[playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Here Pause.png is a image showing Pause Button.

NSError *err;

AVAudioSession *audioSession=[AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

//   audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&err];

[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

audioPlayer.delegate=self;

[audioPlayer play];

playing=YES;

}

else if (playing==YES)

{

[playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[audioPlayer pause];

playing=NO;

}

}
```

Comment: What does urlsArray return?

Comment: Actually, nevermind. But what kind of data does it return? Is it encoded and of the file formats AVAudioPlayer can play? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW48. Look at Table 1-1

Comment: check the link it might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856445/get-an-audio-stream-from-uri-and-play-it-on-iphone

Comment: @Uma_Shanker_Tiwari thanks for your response.I have 12 playlists.if i click the uitableviewcell i want to play that corresponding song.

Answer (score 0):

why is the line where you initialize the audioplayer commented?

> //   audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url
>   error:&err];

try with this

```
audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:urlsArray[0] error:nil];
```

Comment: thanks for your response.But i got exception of the line.urlsArray is the array value.i declare like "urlsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];"

Comment: ya initialized brother

Comment: audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlsArray[0]] error:nil]; ??

Comment: thats the same answer that @sunny shah

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSError *error=nil;   
    NSString *strURl=[urlsArray objectAtIndex:0];
strURl =[strURl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         audioPlayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURl ] error:&error];
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
```

Comment: @Brother thanks for your response.But i got error this line of code "     audioPlayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURl ] error:&error];" like "passing address of non-local object to auto releasing parameter for write-back"

Comment: When you run in the browser its play or not?

Comment: ya,if i copy and paste the url in browser it is play

Comment: @brother chceck this line of code "strURL =[strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];" you are using strURL Two times

Comment: yaa i know check with this

Comment: but i got error brother..why because you are using " NSString *strURl=[urlsArray objectAtIndex:0];
strURL =[strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
"

Comment: 2014-03-19 12:00:34.946 MAstro[949:907] Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)"
2014-03-19 12:00:39.114 MAstro[949:907] ErrorDomain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)".........i got exception like this way

Comment: NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: strURl options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:nil ];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:songFile error:& error];

Comment: its a proble, with URl try with NSData