# LiveStream: NSURL not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to test out a live streaming application but nothing is working. I tried using the links people used on youTube and still nothing. here is my code.

```
-(IBAction)LiveStream:(id)sender {
    NSString *stream = @"http://www.surfmusic.de/radio-station/techno4ever-dsl,8457.html";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stream];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [music loadRequest:request];
}
```

This is an active station, listening to it right now. But when it loads on the simulator it just says 'error' beside play button.

Am I doing something wrong or is the link supposed to be special?

Comment: Show the code where you declare an initialize the variable music

Comment: Also, did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856445/get-an-audio-stream-from-uri-and-play-it-on-iphone?

Comment: its: IBOutlet UIWebView *music;

Comment: No offense, techno ist nicht so meins, but It loads fine on my simulator.

Comment: so it works on yours but on my simulator it says error :( and I just randomly clicked techno and it had a good mix playing lol

Comment: and if anyone can help!! The techno is now working but i still have to click 'play' on the web view. can i make it so it automatically starts to play?