# How to stream audio as data is downloaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avplayer, core-audio

How can I take data as it is being downloaded/received by my device and then play it through the iPhone speaker? I do not want to wait until the audio is fully downloaded.

Platform: iOS 8.0 +

File type: WAV

Sample Rate: 4000 Hz

Audio Type: PCM, 16 bit

Audio Channels: 1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856445/get-an-audio-stream-from-uri-and-play-it-on-iphone

Comment: https://github.com/muhku/FreeStreamer

Answer (score 1):

To minimize latency, pre-enable the apps audio session and request very short buffer durations.  Start the RemoteIO Audio Unit output running with the output callback polling a circular buffer, otherwise playing a bit of silence.  Then format (resample if needed) and store samples of the wave file, as any portions of the wave file are received, in the circular buffer.